# stip slashes from database return with while loop

Tags: php, stripslashes

Can I loop through DB results and remove Slashes?

(I started getting more slashes everytime I edited the text and put it back into the DB)

```
$db = new connection();

$query = "SELECT * FROM ITEMS, ALPACA_SALES WHERE ITEMS.uid = '$id' AND ALPACA_SALES.uid = ITEMS.uid";
$results = $db->query($query);

$data = array();    
while($info = mysql_fetch_array($results))
{
    $data[] = stripslashes($info);
}
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/content/myfile.php  on line 78
```

When I add the data to the database I do the following:

```
if (!empty($_POST['more_text']))
{
    $more_text = addslashes($_POST['more_text']); 
}
else
{
    $error = false;
    $error_message = "Please add a description.";
}
```

And then I use UPDATE for the insert into the DB:

```
$query2 = "UPDATE ALPACA_SALES SET more_text = '$more_text' WHERE uid = '$id'"; 

$result = $db->query($query2);
```

Comment: We need to see your insert query. There is a problem with it

Comment: See my edit above for the updating the DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't run stripslashes() on an array, which is what $info is from storing mysql_fetch_array($results).  You could iterate through $info and strip slashes on each entry, or explicitly strip slashes if you don't need to do all of them.

```
$i=0;
while($infoarray = mysql_fetch_assoc($results))
    {
        foreach($infoarray as $field=>$value){
            $data[$i][$field] = stripslashes($value);
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Edit: You can also create a small function to strip slashes in an array, as outlined in the documentation here: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

```
function stripslashes_deep($value)
{
    $value = is_array($value) ?
                array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                stripslashes($value);

    return $value;
}

// Example
$array = array("f\\'oo", "b\\'ar", array("fo\\'o", "b\\'ar"));
$array = stripslashes_deep($array);
```

Comment: When I use the code above and then try to echo the values like so: <? echo $data[0]['more_text']; ?>  I get the number 1  and to test I echo $field  but get 7more_text  Sorry if I am not grasping this but I appreciate your help.

Comment: I made a few changes. I had forgotten to increment where we're storing things in $data with each row. I also changed it to mysql_fetch_assoc so we get the proper key=>value pairs. I would suggest adding a print_r($infoarray) at the beginning of the where loop and a print_r($data) after it finishes to see how things are structured and to better troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and I will remember the print_r for testing.

Answer (score 1):

Do not do that. stripslashes() is not enough to make a string safe to use in an SQL statement. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements and bound parameters instead.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. This form is in an admin area so I hadn't though to much about security. I was just getting weird results from the quotes and apostrophes.